# How to structure MongoDB table to allow quick calculations based on cumulative numbers under constraints?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Our DB has hundreds of thousands of rows of data where a particular entity amasses points in a certain entry based on certain constraints.

Let us call the entities `A1`, `A2`…`A1000`. Let the constraints be `X1`, `X2`, `X3`…`Xn`. The constraints are "met" in the document by setting the value to 1 for that field, like say for one document, `X1` field has value 1, `X45` has 0, `X49` has 1, etc.

Every document, chronicles, serially, the points which say the main entity in it (like `A1`, `A2`, etc.) accrued in that scenario under a given set of constraints - say `A1` amassed 71 points under conditions of `X1`, `X87` and `X90` - this is one document.

Similarly supposed second row says `A2` amassed 92 points under `X21`, `X45` and `X67`.

Now next row has `A1` again, this time amassing 9 points, but under criteria `X1` and `X90` only.

Next row - `A1` again, under `X1`, `X56`, `X71` and `X90`, say 45 points.

Next row has `A4`, under `X1`, `X90`, `X67`, amassing 345 points.

Next row has `A4`, under `X1`, `X56`, `X67`, amassing 12 points.

We have millions of rows like this - where the entity can amass any points under any combination of criteria, serially, each document representing one scenario.

Question - the queries run like “Who amassed 90 points the fastest under criteria `X1` and `X90`”. In this case, from our data above, none of the documents from entity `A2` fits the criteria, `A1` does - all three documents. `A4` does in only 1 of the 2 documents, its second document has no `X90`, only `X1`, and hence it does not meet the criteria.

However, the cumulative numbers show that it took `A1` three documents (meaning three entries) to amass 90 - the first three (totalling 125, exceeding 90). While, `A4`, in the very first document, amasses 345, thus automatically crossing 90, and since it took 1 document, lesser than the 3 documents `A1` took, we can safely say that `A4` amassed 90 points the fastest.

Let us assume all documents have an insertion time entry which we can use to sort them during query, since this class of queries require them to be sorted on basis of insertion into the DB.

Now what kind of data modelling or indexing can enable us to calculate these kind of calculations super fast? We cannot precompute aggregates at every document level, since the number of combinations `X1`, `X2`…`X100` can have are virtually infinite and it is not scaleable to compute totals under each combination and store them in the document, while the query can come with any combination of `X1`…`X100` conditions.

Comment: Is the insertion time gap between consecutive documents of the same entity fixed (one minute for example)? It will be easier if we can calculate the maximal number of documents needed to amass  the points and then bound the insertion time from both start and end timestamps...Can we say (for example) that 90 points is maximum 90 documents which means maximum 90 periods from the input insertion time?

Comment: The insertion time is not important actually. My mistake. The insertion time is just a way to find out the order of insertion, since in many DBs, the order of retrieval is not necessarily same as that of insertion, so, we can have the insertion time as a check, since the order determines the pace at which the points were amassed, 212 points being amassed in the 100th document for A1 is different than being in the 2nd document itself, since the latter means that A1 definitely crossed a cumulative total of 212 points in the second document itself.

Comment: What happens if a certain entity needs 2 documents to amasses the points, but between them, there are 5 documents which do not meet the conditions. Are they still count as 2 or as 7?

Comment: They are counted as 7. Let me add that clarification, it is cumulative total, we do not get to pick and choose.

Comment: Since the beginning of time?

Comment: Umm, sorry, what since beginning of time? Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: The accumulation is always calculated from the first document of this entity inserted to the db. Not from a specific insertion time. Correct?

Comment: This [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fnQ-vpML3x4) probably isn't optimal (or even correct?), but it may be worth a view.

Comment: @nimrodserok yes, it is calculated from the first document. Of course the first matching document may come much later, but all the documents that come before count as "cost" incurred before the matching documents start appearing to add the cumulative total to reach to the desired point, if at all ever.

Comment: @rickhg12hs looks promising. Why don't you add a full fledged answer explaining the query a bit so that I can upvote it and may be add some comments directly  underneath it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one option is to use the natural data model (for example):

```
 {
    "_id": 1,
    "entity": "A1",
    "points": 71,
    "X1": 1,
    "X87": 1,
    "X90": 1,
    "timestamp": ISODate("2023-08-01T10:00:00.0Z")
  },
```

With a query based on `$setWindowFields`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$setWindowFields: {
      partitionBy: "$entity",
      sortBy: {timestamp: 1},
      output: {
        count: {
          $sum: 1,
          window: {documents: ["unbounded", "current"]}
        },
        amass: {
          $sum: {
            $cond: [
              {$and: [{$eq: ["$X1", 1]}, {$eq: ["$X90", 1]}]},
              "$points",
              0
            ]
          },
          window: {documents: ["unbounded", "current"]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$match: {amass: {$gte: 90}}},
  {$group: {_id: "$entity", count: {$first: "$count"}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/R6YKJR3B4PK)

Comment: Works. I like the idea that the query returns the number of instances it took to amass the sum. Additional question, if you don't mind, we have similar category of questions - like who was the fastest to amass 10 instances of X1 and X2 together in one document (naturally it must include those documents where both X1 and X2 were not present as well before that count is reached). Can a query be formulated to give us that list of results, sorted, along with the number of documents the entities took to reach that count?

Comment: What does `sortBy: {insertion: 1}` do?  Also, showing your data model here would be helpful, since none was provided. I'm also wondering if a different data model might avoid having to scan the entire collection for each query.

Comment: @rickhg12hs, a typo, thanks :) I'll update. I couldn't not think of a better query so far...

Comment: If a data model and query strategy can't be made that can utilize an index, the OP's goal of a 1-2 second query response time with millions of documents seems a stretch.

Comment: @SexyBeast, regarding your question, it is a minor change on the current query: just replace `"$points"` with `1`: [like this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6OtEmyjHVu-)

Comment: @rickhg12hs, I agree. An index on the `entity` and `timestamp` will help, but I think 1-2 second query response time on such a query on millions of rows is very ambitious... Can't think on a better way though...This is a place to start from...

Comment: @nimrodserok, how much do you anticipate will be the query time for such kind of queries on millions of documents? Let us assume that everything that can be indexed, will be indeed, and in addition, if additional checkpoint accumulations need to be stored as well (all of them are not possible of course, since the combinations are infinite in number) to expedite queries, that too can be done.

Comment: It depends on many parameters, such as your machine and so on, but also on the number of unique entities, since each entity is calculated independently, 1K entities on 1M lines is only 1K documents per entity . Also, if you can provide a limit to the number of documents needed to complete the count, this can be helpful as well (for example, consider only the first 1k documents per entity to find the fastest)

Comment: Another approach that I tried to explain earlier, if you only need the faster entity, is to use the timestamps to match only a small number (x) of documents per entity, and if no entity amass the required target, run again with 2x and so on...If you could use a `$match ` step before the rest of the query it will be very helpful

Comment: @nimrodserok, got it. Thanks a lot! I will post new questions based on the findings.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to recommend a data model without knowing the full range of queries that may be desired, but here's a stab at the problem.

Documents could be something like this:

```json
{
  "_id": 1,
  "entity": "A1",
  "points": 71,
  "constraints": ["X1", "X87", "X90"],
  "timestamp": ISODate("2023-08-01T10:00:00.0Z")
}
```

*“Who amassed 90 points the fastest under criteria X1 and X90?”* ... could be an aggregation pipeline like this.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "constraints": {
        // only interested in these constraints
        "$all": ["X1", "X90"]
      }
    }
  },
  { // include pointsSum field in surviving docs
    // include first timestamp to calculate elapsed time
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "partitionBy": "$entity",
      "sortBy": {"timestamp": 1},
      "output": {
        "pointsSum": {
          "$sum": "$points",
          "window": {
            "documents": ["unbounded", "current"]
          }
        },
        "firstTime": {
          "$first": "$timestamp"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // only care about docs where pointsSum >= 90
    "$match": {
      "pointsSum": {"$gte": 90}
    }
  },
  { // calculate elapsed time
    "$set": {
      "elapsedTime": {
        "$subtract": ["$timestamp", "$firstTime"]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // rank the docs by elapsed time
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "sortBy": {"elapsedTime": 1},
      "output": {
        "rank": {"$rank": {}}
      }
    }
  },
  { // only care about the fastest (could be ties)
    "$match": {
      "rank": 1
    }
  },
  { // output desired fields
    "$project": {
      "entity": 1,
      "timestamp": 1,
      "elapsedTime": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8o4TQKqaqKb).

Comment: Thanks. This looks wicked cool. Since you asked about the range of queries it is supposed to support, let me throw in some similar looking queries - like suppose every time `X1` constraint is met, it is a plus one. For each entity - `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, etc. So, a query can be - who was the quickest to amass 10 `A1`s, meaning which entity reached a count of 10 instances of `X1` field value being 1 in minimal number of documents (must be at least 10!). Or say, a combination - who was the quickest to amass 15 instances of `X1` and `X2` together, etc.

Comment: @SexyBeast Using the same data model with `"$setWindowFields"`, the same ranking/matching could be done.  With millions of documents, depending on what you are accumulating, have a good `"$match"` as the first stage (with an index on that/those fields) will be very important if you need speed.

Comment: Thanks Rick. Definitely will add index for all those fields. Will it be possible for you to add another code example for the second class of queries I asked? Just so that I can visualise the query patterns? And also, with millions of documents, assuming a machine with sufficient RAM (let's talk 50-60 GB plus or even more), can this document return results in 1-2 seconds or less?

Comment: If I understand correctly, this will not due, as the first `$match` is not right. According to the remarks, the documents which do not meet the conditions need to counted as well

Comment: Please check out `A7` on my playground. According to my understanding the count should be 3...

Comment: @nimrodserok yes, you are right, those documents are also needed to be counted, since they are the "cost" which the entity had to pay before it could amass the count under the said constraints.

Comment: @nimrodserok You are right, I did not see that in the question ... so I just answered the question.